# Add multiple="multiple" attribute to categories dropdown

Tags: categories, html

I have a dropdown with Regular select. I need a dropdown with Multiselect. I added the JavaScript script file inside `header.php`, now I need add string `multiple="multiple"`.

In firebug I `multiple = "multiple"` in a string

> [image]

Now I need add string `multiple="multiple"` in to this block but I don't know how do this:

```
<?php 
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID,"listing_category" );
  $terms = isset($terms[0]) ? $terms[0]->term_id : "";

  if(get_field("custom_attributes_input_types","options") == "Dropdowns"):
    wp_dropdown_categories( 
      array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'listing_category', 
        'hiera`enter code here`rchical'=>1, 
        'show_option_none'=>__('Choose Category:','um_lang'), 
        'name' => 'listing_category', 
        'hide_empty' => false, 
        'selected' => $terms
      )
    );
  else:
?>
```

Comment: `get_field()` is _no_ native WP API function. Is this a plugin?

Comment: [Standard solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261094/105285)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the source of [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.8/wp-includes/category-template.php#L300). It uses [`walk_category_dropdown_tree()`](http://queryposts.com/function/walk_category_dropdown_tree/) to render the output. Right after that you have [a filter named `wp_dropdown_cats`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.8/wp-includes/category-template.php#L374) that allows altering the final MarkUp:

```
$output = apply_filters( 'wp_dropdown_cats', $output );
```

You could now use a Regex and `preg_replace` or parse it using `DOMDocument`, etc.

Keep in mind that you should change the `select` elements `Name` attribute as well - else you wouldn't be able to save an array. Example:

```
<select multiple name="foo[]" ...>
```

Still you'll need to change the `walker` argument and rewrite the Walker itself. The reason can be read [in `Walker_CategoryDropdown::start_el`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/08a1d44ba5e9c0b9a37f02b616f7d1be7759b650/wp-includes/category-template.php#L971):

```
if ( $category->term_id == $args['selected'] )
    $output .= ' selected="selected"';
```

As you can see currently it's checking only a single value, not an array. So basically you'll need a check against your array. Example overriding method that checks against an array:

```
public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);

    $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
    $output .= "<option class=\"level-{$depth}\" value=\"{$category->term_id}\"";

    # >>> HERE WE GO:
    if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected'] ) )
        $output .= ' selected="selected"';

    $output .= '>';
    $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
    if ( $args['show_count'] )
        $output .= "({$category->count})";
    $output .= "</option>";
}
```

Put above method in a new class that extends `Walker_CategoryDropdown` and put that new Walker class as argument into your args array for `wp_dropdown_categories()`:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'walker'   => new Custom_Walker_CategoryDropdown
    'selected' => get_option( 'foo' )
    # etc…
) );
```

As you can see, I added the option `foo`, which comes from the `name="foo[]"` above. The specific implementation is up to you. This answer shall just serve as guide towards your solution.

Comment: [Standard solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261094/105285)

Comment: @MahdiY How is all that string manipulation a "standard solution"?

Comment: Clean, readable and easy to use